# Why is the EventArgs constructor not protected?

Tags: c#, events, singleton

I'm wondering why the `EventArgs` constructor isn't protected as it seems like waste (although tiny) to allocate resources for an empty object for every event, especially when there is a singleton `EventArgs.Empty` that's clearly more efficient to use. This surprises me, especially when other parts of the .NET do have a protected/private constructor to avoid multiple, unnecessary allocations, e.g. `Comparer<T>`.

Are there any cases where creating a `new EventArgs()` (not a subclass) actually makes sense, or is the constructor merely available to ease the usage for non-experienced developers?

Comment: Perhaps it's serialization-related? I don't know much about the default binary serialization, but it could be relevant...

Comment: If you're going there.... why isn't `object` an `abstract` class with a `protected` constructor ;p (we should assume here that a sensible class would have been provided for sync-locks; maybe instances of `Monitor` ;p)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that its because the `EventArgs` class has the `ComVisible` attribute set to `true`.

This is supported by the following [FxCop rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182203%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> A reference type that is specifically marked as visible to COM contains a public parameterized constructor but does not contain a public default (parameterless) constructor.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why that has an impact? I'm not especially familiar with COM.

Comment: +1 almost certainly this is right.  COM doesn't have parameterized constructors, so ComVisible classes have to have a public default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

A bigger question is "Why always use EventArgs, even if your event does not need any information?". If EventArgs did not have a public constructor you'd not be able to do this.

A good advantage is that if in future you do want to pass information any existing code will still compile. For example the following class started out using just EventArgs, but now passes a string containing some "useful information".

```
class SomeEventSource
{
    public event EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> MyEvent;

    public void FireTheEvent()
    {
        MyEvent(this, new SomeEventArgs("This information is interesting"));
    }
}

class SomeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public SomeEventArgs(string interestingInformation)
    {
        InterestingInformation = interestingInformation;
    }
    public string InterestingInformation { get; private set; }
}
```

This client code was written before the change, but it still compiles. If the original had not used EventArgs then the change would have been more expensive to implement.

```
class SomeClient
{
    private readonly SomeEventSource _source;

    public SomeClient()
    {
        _source = new SomeEventSource();
        _source.MyEvent += source_MyEvent;
    }

    public void RunTest()
    {
        _source.FireTheEvent();
    }

    void source_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

There is an annotation on EventArg's constructor which enables it to be optimised in certain situations. EventArgs itself is marked Serializable and ComVisible. Any subclass you create will take advantage of these and fit the pattern.